# symbol set icons not showing in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, icons

On this website I have a nice template I bought some time ago, which uses symbol set icons to show a little cat or a wifi symbol, to symbolize that pets are allowed in my home and there is plenty of wifi: http://leeuwwitje.nl

But in internet explorer 11 at work, the symbols are not shown. Instead I only see the keywords. I probably should include a little script to make this work in IE, but I cant seem to find it.

Strange thing is that in the demo of the template all is working all right, but in my site this problem occurs.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with font-support. Could you show some CSS code on how the icon-font/icons are loaded into CSS?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I actually do not know how the connection is made between the icon and the html. This is for example the html for the cat: 
   <i class="ss-icon">cat</i>
In firefox and chrome the result is a cute looking cat, but in ie, it does no work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually add an icon class to your span.   It looks like all of your spans contain the font you want so update them from:

```
<span class="ss-icon">cat</span>
```

To:

```
 <span class="ss-icon ss-cat"></span>
```

Not sure where your icon list is but these seem to work for me [ui.bellhelicopter.com](https://ui.bellhelicopter.com/assets/fonts/ss-geomicons-squared/documentation.html)

```html
<link href="https://ui.bellhelicopter.com/assets/fonts/ss-geomicons-squared/webfonts/ss-geomicons-squared.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <ul>
     <li style="list-style-type:none"><i style="font-size:24px" class='ss-icon ss-cat'></i></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. 

It is strange that this is not necessary in Firefox. Because the html is a product of a wordpress plugin, now I need to find out how to get the plugin to add this class name.

Comment: Of course when I added the ss-cat to the class attribute, there were two cats. (my luck) So I emptied the tag, like in your example. I suspect there probably is a more elegant way, but this will do. Thanks!